# How to extend Facebook access_token automatically to keep access after 60 days?

Tags: php, facebook, token, extend

Ok, so offline_access has been deprecated. So now, I am able to get 60 days access tokens but is there any way to extend this without user interaction? We have a tool which you can compare a bit with Hootsuite that does a lot of automatic synchronisation. I don't want to bother our users every 60 days to re-authorize again.

Is there any way I can extend an access_token without user interaction?

(We use PHP here by the way)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend long-lived (and short-lived) access tokens but only when the user visits the app.

See below article for more information about this works and how to achieve it:

[Removal of offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

Comment: Hi Mitch, but below that page it says:"querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages." Wouldn't that mean that page access_tokens don't expire? Also, all web-apps like Hootsuite all have to ask users to reconnect every 60 days? Sounds so bad...

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I acquire a short-lived user access token. Then, I convert that token into an extended (long-lived) user access token. Using this token, I acquire page access tokens. These page access tokens, contrary to Facebook's documentation, expire in 60 days.

It seems that the community agrees (edit: agreed) that this is a bug. View the Facebook bug page at: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/461517520524921 (edit: FB has since removed this bug report...)

Comment: Looks like FB has removed the bug report.  Boo!